# Magento 2: Templates are not working correctly

Tags: magento2, template, localhost

I'm attempting to create my own module with a custom template however in my browser, I am unable to view the 'hello world' output.

```
Gregt/Hello/block - helloworld.php 

    <?php
    namespace GregT\Hello\Block;

    class Helloworld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
    public function getHelloWorldTxt()
    {
        return 'Hello world!';
       }
    }


Gregt/Hello/controller/index - index.php 

    <?php

    namespace GregT\Hello\Controller\Index;

    use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
     protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, 
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        echo ("hello");
        return $resultPage;
       }
    }

Gregt/Hello/VIEW/frontend/layout - helloworld_index_index.xml

    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/
    Framewo rk/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
      <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="GregT\Hello\Block\Helloworld" name="helloworld" 
    template="GregT_Hello::helloworld.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
    </page>

Gregt/Hello/etc/frontend - routes.xml 

    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="GregT_Hello" />
        </route>
    </router>
    </config>

Gregt/Hello/etc - module.xml 

    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="GregT_Hello" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
    </config>


Gregt/Hello/view/frontend/templates - helloworld.phtml 

    <h1><?php echo $block->getHelloWorldTxt(); ?></h1>

Gregt/Hello - registration.php 

    <?php

    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'GregT_Hello',
     __DIR__
    );

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWuFv.png
```

Comment: try with this `<h1><?php echo $block->getHelloWorldTxt(); ?></h1>`

Comment: Your layout file is at wrong place I have added the answer with the correct place and content.

Comment: Hi, Greg, welcome. You don't need to add "SOLVED" to the question, and also don't need to tag the title (the tagging system will do that for you). I've posted an edit removing those elements from the title. The stackexchange system will mark the question as solved (the green checkmark on accepted answer) and also show the main tag automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check below solution, May be helpful to you.

You have created `Gregt/Hello/controller/index - index.php`
And `Gregt/Hello/block - helloworld.php`

Also layout file wrong, It should be `Gregt/Hello/view/frontend/layout - helloworld_index_index.xml`

folder name should be Controller not controller, Block not block. Please correct folder name and check.

Comment: Changed all these but still isn't showing

Comment: Also you should apply changes as per @Amit bera

Answer (score 4):

You did a small mistake

```
<?php echo $this->getHelloWorldTxt(); ?>
```

Should be

```
<?php echo $block->getHelloWorldTxt(); ?>
```

Also have to change

```
name="helloworld" 
template="helloworld.phtml"
```

to

```
name="helloworld" 
template="GregT_Hello::helloworld.phtml"
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Controller path should be like this:

   ```
   app/code/Gregt/Hello/Controller/Index/Index.php
   ```
2. in `execute()` try to put inside `return "Hello";`
3. Call this path : `domaine.com/helloworld` and see If you see `Hello`

Comment: Hi, I'm now able to see Hello at the top of the page.

Comment: Did you updated the files to Capitalize letters and refreshed th cache ?

Comment: Yes but I don't think it is using the template and instead just echoing from index.php

Comment: Yes I mean the controller files from `app/code/Gregt/Hello/controller/index/index.php` to `app/code/Gregt/Hello/Controller/Index/Index.php`

Comment: Yeah i did that

Comment: Try `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`, `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Comment: Done all, still nothing

Comment: I don't why ! you have some errors in your module including the controller and layout but before to display your template it is necessary to debug the controller first before continue to the layout and the template, obviously it hangs on the controller and it is not normal

Comment: Thanks for your help, was this in the end Gregt/Hello/view/frontend/layout - helloworld_index_index.xml

Comment: yes I knew it, I told you in the previous comment (errors in your module including the controller and `layout`) but it was necessary to debug the controller before, the essential is that you have solved your problem, good luck  :)

Answer (score 2):

Your lyout file should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="GregT\Hello\Block\Helloworld" name="helloworld"
                   template="GregT_Hello::helloworld.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And Place must be at `app/code/GregT/Hello/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml`